# Display image in Visual Studio not saved as resource

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to display an image, the URL of which I've loaded via `GetOpenFilename`. This isn't in itself the problem, I have also tried simply copying and pasting the URL of an existing image from a resource file into the `LoadBitmap` function, and the HBITMAP I'm assigning is NULL. How can I make this work?

```
void GetUserSprite(HWND hwnd, HBITMAP &Image, HBITMAP &Mask)
{
using namespace std;
OPENFILENAME ofn;
char szFileName[MAX_PATH + 1];
ZeroMemory(&ofn, sizeof(ofn));
ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(ofn);
ofn.hwndOwner = hwnd;
ofn.lpstrFilter = "Bitmaps (*.JPG, *.BMP, *.DIB, *.gif, *.JPEG, *.jpe, *.png)\0*.jpg;*.bmp;*.jpeg;*.png";
ofn.lpstrFile = szFileName;
ofn.lpstrFile[0] = '\0';
ofn.nMaxFile = MAX_PATH;
ofn.Flags = OFN_EXPLORER | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST | OFN_HIDEREADONLY | OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST;
ofn.lpstrDefExt = "bmp";
if(GetOpenFileName(&ofn))
{
    bDefaultSprite = false;
    strImageURL = szFileName;
    Image = LoadBitmap(GetModuleHandle(NULL), strImageURL.c_str());
    if (Image == NULL)
    {
        MessageBox(hwnd, "Well, that sucks...", "", NULL);
    }
    Mask = CreateBitmapMask(Image, RGB(0,0,0));
    InvalidateRect(hwnd, NULL, TRUE);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);
}
}
```

Comment: MSDN says about [`LoadBitmap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145033.aspx): `The LoadBitmap function loads the specified bitmap resource from a module's executable file`. AFAIU, you are trying to load from an image instead. Had you checked the `GetLastError` return code, you'd see `ERROR_RESOURCE_DATA_NOT_FOUND` or `ERROR_RESOURCE_NAME_NOT_FOUND`. It's also recommended to use `LoadImage` nowadays.

Comment: Have you had any success with that?

Comment: @Joulukuusi Sorry for the late reply, but not yet. I've been using `LoadBitmap` exclusively so far, and am having to convert my program to work with HANDLEs instead. I've been looking [here](http://tipsandtricks.runicsoft.com/Cpp/BitmapTutorial.html) for information on that.

Comment: You don't really have to do that, as the declaration is `typedef HANDLE HBITMAP`. Could you explain what you're trying to do? Trying to load images from a resource file, or from an image file?

Comment: @Joulukuusi from an image file. I can load quite easily from a resource file, but image files is where my problems lie.

Comment: Call the function like `LoadImage(NULL, strImageURL.c_str(), IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE)`. The first parameter means you don't want to load from a resource file, and provide the full path to image in the second one.

Comment: @Joulukuusi Once again, sorry for the (extremely) late reply, but this works perfectly now. Thank you very much.